# how to extract word that is followed by numeric using php

Tags: php, regex

Problem here is that, i need to extract word and numeric that follows after a number out of a string.

Here below is the two types of string from which i need to extract that particular text

String - 1

```
   1 .COIMBATORE (C) WARD NO 55 Singanallur .
```

String - 2

```
1 .COIMBATORE (C) Singanallur WARD NO 55.
```

I need to extract only that "Ward No + number ".

I tried using regex method with explode function

```
$texts = '1 .COIMBATORE (C) AMMANKULAM NORTH VAIKALMEDU WARD NO 55';
$var=explode ("/WARD NO ([0-9]+)/i",$texts);
```

But i'm not getting the output. What shall i do

Comment: Use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match), not explode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `preg_match' to match regular expression in PHP.

Like:

```
preg_match('/WARD NO [0-9]+/', $stringToSearch, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Here $stringToSearch is your searched string (i.e. 'COIMBATORE (C) WARD NO 55 Singanallur .') and you will get matched result in $match variable.

Comment: Yeah. Worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Husain, please accept the answer in case it worked. Thanks :)